# Taurus GUI doesn't reflect parse parameters if it was used with variables

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I found this while I am working on Taurus GUI, and I noticed the -gui tool does not really reflect the right behavior when I use parameters with variables.

Please let me know if this is a bug or its how it is designed.

my yaml config.
[image]

Running

> bzt myYaml.yaml -gui

[image: paramter holding threads]

However, when I created a variable that holds the value `${__groovy(Math.round(92/100 * ${__P(threads)}),)}`

`bzt myYaml.yaml -gui` didn't show that this was configured correctly and default the thread group threads to 1.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared in [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) are initialized when test is started which is why the plugin displays 0.

While if you set the value below, it is evaluated inline:

> ${__groovy(Math.round(92/100 * ${__P(threads,100)}),)}

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using 1.13.3, macOS

Comment: Oups, I misunderstood question, I fixed my answer

Comment: I see now. 
My use case was to try to add a user defined variable defined in two places, one is for testing my use cases from Jmeter and the other from Taurus. 

Is there is another way of doing it?

Comment: Of course! I appreciate your help and following up so quick.